# st (Simple Terminal) doesn't show up when selecting alternative x-terminal-emulator

Tags: terminal-emulator, suckless-terminal

Apologies for the absolutely terrible title, I had no idea how to phrase it.

So, when I run the command `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator` in an attempt to change my default terminal emulator to st (Simple Terminal, one of the suckless programs), it doesn't show up. Is this related to st, by design, needing to be compiled from source, and how do I fix it?

```
adamfra@pop-os:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
[sudo] password for adamfra:
There are 2 choices for the alternative x-terminal-emulator (providing /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator).

  Selection    Path                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/terminator               50        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/terminator               50        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you've compiled st and it's at /usr/local/bin/st then...

```
# Register st terminal
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator x-terminal-emulator /usr/local/bin/st 50

# Select your terminal
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

Note: Enter the correct path to st in the first statement.